# Folland theorem 6.19: $p=\infty$

Tags: measure-theory, inequality, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces, convolution

Consider the following theorem from Folland's book "Real analysis: Modern techniques and their applications":

[image]

In the book, it can be found on p194 (second edition). I understand the proof of the theorem for part (a) completely. However if $p = \infty$, I don't understand why (b) is true.

In Folland's book, the following is written in the proof:

> This is a simple application of the monoticity of the integral.

Can someone explain me why this is true? We have to prove that
$$\left\|\int_Y f(-,y) d\nu(y)\right\|_\infty\le \int_Y \|f(-,y)\|_\infty d\nu(y)$$
so for example it suffices to show that
$$\left|\int_Y f(x,y)d\nu(y)\right|\le \int_Y \|f(-,y)\|_\infty d\nu(y)$$
for $\mu$-almost every $x \in X$.

Intuitively, we would want to do the following: If $x$ is in some set $A$ with complement contained in a set of measure $0$, then
$$\left|\int_Y f(x,y)d\nu(y)\right|\le \int_Y |f(x,y)|d\nu(y) \le \int_Y \|f(-,y)\|_\infty d\nu(y)$$
but to justify the last inequality we need to show that
$$\int_Y |f(x,y)|d\nu(y) \le \int_Y \|f(-,y)\|_\infty d\nu(y)$$
for all $x \in A$. However, why is this the case? Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: that $|f(x,y)|\leq \|f(\cdot,y)\|_\infty$   for $\mu\otimes\nu$-a.a. $(x,y)\in X\times Y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The case $p=\infty$ follows by a carefully application of Fubini-Tonelli's theorem.

- Without loss of generality assume $y\mapsto \|f(\cdot,y)\|_\infty$ is finite. Define the set
  $$B=\{(x,y)\in X\times Y: |f(x,y)|>\|f(\cdot,y)\|_\infty\}$$
  This is a measurable set and, by Fubini's theorem, $$\mu\otimes\nu(B)=\int_Y\mu(\{x:|f(x,y)|>\|f(\cdot,y)\|_\infty\})\,\nu(dy)$$
  Since $\mu(\{x:|f(x,y)|>\|f(\cdot,y)\|_\infty\})=0$ for all $y$, we conclude that
  $$|f(x,y)|\leq \|f(\cdot,y)\|_{L_\infty(X,\mu)}\qquad\mu\otimes\nu-\text{a.s.}$$
  Hence, for any  $A\in\mathcal{M}$, $\mathbb{1}_A(x)|f(x,y)|\leq\mathbb{1}_A(x)\|f(\cdot,y)\|_\infty$  $\,\,\mu\otimes\nu$-a.s.
- Another application of Fubini's theorem yields $$\begin{align}\int_A\int_Y|f(x,y)|\,\nu(dy)\,\mu(dx)\leq\mu(A)\int_Y\|f(\cdot,y)\|_{L_\infty(X,\mu)}\,\nu(dy)\tag{1}\quad\forall A\in\mathcal{M},\, \mu(A)<\infty\label{one}\end{align}$$
- If  $\mu(A)<\infty$ define $A^b=\{x\in A: \int_Y|f(x,y)|\,\nu(dy)>\int_Y\|f(\cdot,y)\|_{L_\infty(X,\mu)}\,\nu(dy)\}$ ( $b$ stands for "bad"). If $\mu(A_b)>0$ then, by the positivity property of the Lebesgue integral ($\int_X|\phi|\,d\mu=0$ iff $|\phi|=0$ $\mu$-a.s.) we have that
  $$\int_{A^b}\int_Y|f(x,y)|\,\nu(dy)\,\nu(dx)>\mu(A_b)\int_Y\|f(\cdot,y)\|\,\nu(dy)$$ in contradiction to \eqref{one}; hence $\mu(A^b)=0$.
- To conclude, let $\{A_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ be an $\mathcal{M}$-partition of $X$ with $0<\mu(A_n)<\infty$. Each $A^b_n$ has $\mu$-measure $0$; hence, for $x\in X\setminus\bigcup_nA^b_n$ one has
  $$\int_Y|f(x,y)|\,\nu(dy)\leq \int_Y\|f(\cdot,y)\|_{L_\infty(X,\mu)}\,\nu(dy)$$

Comment: In the third bullet point,  one occurence $\nu$ should be replaced by $\mu$.

Comment: Thanks for the formidable answer!

Comment: Perhaps a little follow-up question: You say that we may assume that $y \mapsto \|f(-,y)\|_\infty$ is finite. This is because we can define $N = \{y \in Y: \|f(-,y)\|_\infty = \infty\}$ (which is measurable since $y \mapsto \|f(-,y)\|_\infty$ is a measurable function) and we can replace $f$ by $f\chi_{X \times N^c}$. Does this seem correct?

Comment: We can assume $y\mapsto\|f(\cdot,y)\|_{L_\infty*X)}$ because by assumption it is integrable (w.r.t.) $\nu(dy)$. As you may remember, integrable functions are finite a.e. Sure, you can replace the value of $\infty$ by say, $0$ or any other nonnegative number, ir remove the bad set altogether without changing anything of importance about $(Y,\nu)$.

Comment: Thanks! Here is a slightly related follow-up question if you have time/interest: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4431158/convolution-inequality-f-star-g-p-le-f-1-g-p-on-locally-compact-g